# How to combine a string and array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array of numbers `0 10 20 30 40` and I am trying to add a string to the front the array so that the output will look like this: `1D: 0 10 20 30 40`

I've tried coding it this way:

```
string="1D: "
new=( $(( $string + ${array[@]} )) )
echo $new
```

Which gives me this error:

```
-bash: 1D: value too great for base (error token is "1D")
```

Can someone assist me in this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
array=(0 10 20 30 40)
string="1D:"
new=("$string" "${array[@]}")
```

Check new array:

```
declare -p new
```

```
declare -a new='([0]="1D:" [1]="0" [2]="10" [3]="20" [4]="30" [5]="40")'
```

Or else:

```
echo "${new[@]}"
1D: 0 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. Is there also a way to make this into a string? This array is meant to be used as input for a flag option in some software I'm using. Normally the line of code would look like `-concat '1D: 0 10 20 30 40'`, but I'm trying to do it like this `-concat '$new'` however the software is giving me an error there. Also, I've adjusted my variable so that it's `new=echo ${new[@]}`

Comment: @djl: That looks like a different problem. You may please post a new question and we'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to prepend a string to an array you can do something like this

```
array=("0" "10" "20" "30" "40")
array=("1D:" "${array[@]}")
echo ${array[@]}
```

output will be

```
1D: 0 10 20 30 40
```